# In C, where are block scoped variables stored?

Tags: c

When we declare a variable inside a block (if. For...) where are those variables stored? I know that the function variables are stored on the stack, and the content dynamic allocated is stored on the heap, but what if we declare a variable inside an if block?

Comment: A block can be defined only within a function.:)

Comment: ..and there is no *syntax* to define a variable on heap.

Comment: Storage of variables is entirely implementation-dependent. In most implementations, all automatic variables are in the stack.

Comment: They're the same as other *local* variables (function parameters, variables declared within a function); they are stored from wherever *automatic* variables are stored.  Normally this means the stack, but they also could be in, say, registers.

Comment: They're stored *in the computer*. That's about all you can be guaranteed. These could be registers, they could be stack, they could be heap, they could be in some other thing which we've never heard of because it's unique to a particular CPU.

Comment: @tadman Nah, you can't guarantee that too. They can be optimized out.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Arguably that's just very optimized storage.

Comment: Another question is whether two nonoverlapping blocks (that is, with mutually-exclusive scope) can re-use each other's storage.  It seems obvious that they could, although I've heard that compilers tend *not* to do this.  (I'm too lazy today to perform any experiments to find out.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Block-scoped variables, along with non-static local variables, have automatic storage duration. What compiler does with it is implementation-defined, though. If the compiler uses stack to manage automatic variables (most compilers do) then block variables end up on the stack. However, it is perfectly valid for the compiler to store these variables in registers, or even to optimize them out at compile time.